# how to implement conversion text speech listen in audio file similar google translator in android

Tags: android, google-translate

i am using google transalate api in my application,i have done in text conversion is ok 
   but translate-text to speech is pending

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

this code i am using how can implement translate text voice in android.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c382dd10f8.png
  this above screenshot display text conversion is ok,click audiobutton image listen translate text in audioplayer how can implemented

my code 
    //audio button click event..........

```
     submit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
          submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
           { public void onClick(View v) 
             { 
                //speech code how can implemented
                  }
             });


  /////////////////// translate button code//////////////////////   
((Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    String fromLan=spineFrom.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String toLan=spineTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.v("check",fromLan+" :"+toLan);
                    translatedText = Translate.execute(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01)).getText().toString(),converStrtoLan(fromLan),converStrtoLan(toLan));
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02)).setText(translatedText);
                        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
                        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
                        startActivityForResult(checkIntent,1);  

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private TextToSpeech mTts;
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, null);
            } else {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        String myText1 = "Did you sleep well?";
        String myText2 = "I hope so, because it's time to wake up.";
        mTts.speak(myText1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        mTts.speak(myText2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
    private Language converStrtoLan(String lan){
        if(lan.equals("ENGLISH") || lan=="ENGLISH"){
            return Language.ENGLISH;
        }else if (lan.equals("SPANISH") || lan=="SPANISH"){
            return Language.SPANISH;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

how can add this audio code in audio click event ,
please forward some valuable response of this code this issue i am struggle for more number of days thanks in advance ..

Comment: please insert only the code snippets inside code block.

Comment: sorry sir change the code snippets inside code block please forward valuable response my problem is conversion voice how can implement in button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do Text To Speech with Android you can use [eyes-free](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free) library

Comment: sorry sir change the code snippets inside code block please forward valuable response my problem is conversion voice how can implement in button click listen voice of conversion text